# Show the data on Prev Next button in each table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having table with multiple rows. Each row is having Prev and Next Button.

Right now, it shows the data on clicking of Prev/Next. However, problem is if I click on row2's next button and then click on row1's prev button then it takes incremetal count from row2's next button. It should start from zero again.

```js
 var exampleDataCount = 0;
 
 $(document).on('change', '.js-column', function() {
        exampleDataCount = 0;
        var $target = $(this).parent().next().next();
        var value = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev_example" data="'+$(this).val()+'"><<</a> '+data[0][$(this).val()]+' <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next_example" data="'+$(this).val()+'">>></a>';
        $target.html(value);
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.prev_example', function() {
  
  if( exampleDataCount != 0 )
            exampleDataCount--;
  
        var $target = $(this).parent();
        var field = $(this).parent().prev().prev().children('select.js-column');
        var value = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev_example" data="'+$(this).attr('data')+'"><<</a> '+data[exampleDataCount][field.val()]+' <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next_example" data="'+$(this).attr('data')+'">>></a>';
        $target.html(value);
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.next_example', function() {
        $('#example_column_heading').val($(this).attr('data'));
  
  if( exampleDataCount != data.length )
            exampleDataCount++;
  
        var $target = $(this).parent();
        var field = $(this).parent().prev().prev().children('select.js-column');
        var value = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev_example" data="'+$(this).attr('data')+'"><<</a> '+data[exampleDataCount][field.val()]+' <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next_example" data="'+$(this).attr('data')+'">>></a>';
        $target.html(value);
    });
```

```html
<tr>
 <td>
  <select class="js-column" name="columns[source][]">
<option value="showstart">showstart</option><option value="showend">showend</option><option value="remedyid">remedyid</option><option value="remedycategory">remedycategory</option><option value="entrytype">entrytype</option><option value="iref" selected="selected">iref</option><option value="ref">ref</option><option value="customer">customer</option><option value="raised">raised</option><option value="priority">priority</option><option value="status">status</option><option value="statusreason">statusreason</option><option value="breachreason">breachreason</option><option </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input class="js-mapped-column" name="columns[name][]" type="text" value="">
 </td>
    <td>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev_example" data="iref">&lt;&lt;</a>  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next_example" data="iref">&gt;&gt;</a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are only making exampleDataCount = 0; only when drop-down changes otherwise it will increment or decrements from the previous value  exampleDataCount variable has.